# How to synchronize two threads using semaphores (without using pthread_join)

Tags: c, operating-system, pthreads, atomic, semaphore

For the C program, it gets the values m and n from the command line arguments and converts them to two integers, respectively. Next, it creates m threads using pthread_create() and
each thread computes the sum of n/m quadruple roots.

Namely, the first thread (i.e. thread 0) computes the sum of quadruple roots from 1 to n/m, the second thread (i.e. thread 1) computes the sum of the quadruple roots from n/m+1 to 2n/m, etc.

When a thread finishes its computation, it prints its partial sum and atomically add it to a shared global variable.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

    pthread_mutex_t x = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;  //Initialize the thread
    int j; //Our index
    double sum = 0.0; //Total sum - shared global variable

    void *calc (void *arg) {
        long tid = (long) arg; //Casting
        double lsum = 0.0; //Partial sums
        for (int i = (tid * j) + 1; i <= (tid + 1) * j; i++) { //We set a range from 1 to n/m and n/m + 1 to 2n/m
            lsum += pow(i,(0.25)); //Adding the quadruple roots in the range
             
        }
        printf("thr %ld: %lf\n", tid, lsum); //Print each thread and its partial sum

        pthread_mutex_lock(&x); //Lock the thread
        sum += lsum; //Partial sums to the total sum
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&x); //Unlock the thread

    }

    int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
        int m = atoi(argv[1]);
        int n = atoi(argv[2]);
        j = n/m;
        pthread_t thr[m];

        for(long i = 0 ; i <= m-1 ; i++){ //Loops throguh and creates the thread
            pthread_create(&thr[i], NULL, calc, (void*)i);
        }

        for(long i=0; i < m; i++) {
            pthread_join(thr[i], NULL); //Lets the main thread know that all of the m computational threads have done the atomic additions
        }

        printf("sum of square roots: %f\n", sum); //Print the total sum
}
```

Run the executable using `./program 2 65536`

The provided C program uses pthread synchronization to let the main thread know that all of the m computational threads.

I am new to semaphores. Is there anyway, the program is modified to **report the additions using semaphores, but not pthread_join()**.

Comment: A barrier might make more sense than a semaphore.

Comment: Using a semaphore would be more complicated. The main thread could set a semaphore to a value equal to the number of child threads, and each thread should decrement it by 1 after finishing its work, and after starting all threads the main thread can wait for the semaphore to become 0. The purpose of `pthread_join` is mainly to wait for the thread's end. You should do this anyway even if you use other mechanisms to know when the thread has finished some work.

Comment: Tip: Be consistent. `for(long i = 0 ; i <= m-1 ; i++)` and `for(long i=0; i < m; i++)` perform identical tasks, so why are they written differently.

Comment: Tip: You are using a `long` to hold value that can fit in an `int`. No use doing that.

Comment: Tip: `(void*)i` is wrong. `(void*)(intptr_t)i` is better. Similarly, you need `(long)(intptr_t)arg` or just `(intptr_t)arg` in the function.

Comment: Your add is thread safe because of locking, not because it's atomic.  If you'd used `atomic_fetch_add(&sum, lsum)`, *then* you could call it atomic, and wouldn't need the lock/unlock.  You'd still need something to wake up the main thread after all `n` threads have done their adds, like perhaps a separate counter of completions.  (`if (1 == atomic_fetch_add(&thread_working, -1) ) { we were the last worker, notify the main thread; }`)  Without C++20 `std::wait` and `std::notify`, you'd have to roll your own mechanism; vs. having the main thread `std::wait` on `atomic_int threads_working`.

Comment: Neither `(void*)i` nor `(long)arg` is wrong, @ikegami.  C explicitly permits conversions back and forth between *any* integer type and any pointer type.  These have implementation-defined behavior, and technically, the combination of the two is not guaranteed to successfully convey an integer value, but interposing additional conversions to `intptr_t` soes not rescue that.  (`intptr_t` serves the opposite purpose -- to represent an object pointer as an integer and then recover the original pointer).

Comment: @John Bollinger, Re "*Neither `(void*)i` nor `(long)arg` is wrong*", As far as I'm concerned, relying on implementation-defined behavior for no reason is wrong. // Re "*`intptr_t` serves the opposite*", Yeah, I know. Thought I had mentioned that. But it's least it's right size and it's a common practice for `pthread_create`

Answer (score 1):

[I just have time for a quick answer.]

---

**Option 1**

Create a semaphore initialized to the negative of the number of threads, plus one (`1-m`).

When a thread's work is done, up/post/signal the semaphore.

In the main thread, down/wait the semaphore.

---

**Option 2**

Create a semaphore initialized to zero.

When a thread's work is done, up/post/signal the semaphore.

In the main thread, down/wait the semaphore *m* times.

---

Note that you still need to join the threads to reap them.

Note that a barrier might make more sense than a semaphore.

Comment: Assuming to goal is to replace all synchronization objects with semaphores, **a** semaphore isn't sufficient.  `sum += lsum;` is not atomic, so it needs to be protected by a semaphore separate from any semaphore used to reap threads.  And I'm sure the next lesson will be how to drive screws with a sledgehammer.  Followed by how to cut down the mightiest tree in the forest with a herring.

Comment: Neither POSIX semaphores nor Sys V semaphores support negative semaphore values.  There might be semaphore implementations the do support such values, but I don't know any myself.

Comment: @Andrew Henle Re "*Assuming to goal is to replace all synchronization objects with semaphores*", That wasn't remotely close to the question asked. The rest of the comment is ...offtopic ramblings? No idea what your point is or how it relates to my answer.

Comment: @John Bollinger, Really? hmmm.  Will update in a bit